# Spark scala dataframe for loop

Tags: scala, loops, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

my input dataframe looks like this :

```
    index    bucket    time    ap   station    rssi
    0         1        00:00   1       1       -84.0
    1         1        00:00   1       3       -67.0
    2         1        00:00   1       4       -82.0
    3         1        00:00   1       2       -68.0
    4         2        00:15   1       3       -83.0
    5         2        00:15   1       2       -82.0
    6         2        00:15   1       4       -80.0
    7         2        00:15   1       1       -72.0
    8         3        00:30   1       4       -85.0
    9         3        00:30   1       3       -77.0
    10        3        00:30   1       2       -70.0
```

i'm new to scala spark and i would like to loop over the data like this :

```
for each ap 
   for each station 
      for each bucket 
         if rssi(previous bucket)<rssi(bucket)
         print message
```

Here is the start of my spark app :

```
object coveralg {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("coveralg").getOrCreate()
        import spark.implicits._
        val input_data =  spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load(args(0))

    }
}
```

but i don't know how to implement a loop over a dataframe and select values to do the if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataFrame aren't design for that.
They are design to to apply the same transformation to each record or reduce them.
You could add a column with a `Boolean` implementing your `if` :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.partitionBy($"ap",$"station",$"bucket").
        orderBy(unix_timestamp($"time")).
        rangeBetween(Long.MinValue, -1)

val df = input_data.withColumn("shouldPrintMessage",when(max($"rssi".over(w))>$"rssi",true))
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. Maybe i should use textFile import instead of DataFrame to loop over rows of my log ?